# Should I encrypt login password on Javascript or on backend?

Tags: security, encryption

I have a small website using Html,Css,Javascript and PhP. The website contains a basic login page where the user has to enter his password. Said password is then sent to php, which in its turn, encrypts it using SHA-512 and adds it to database.

So I started wondering. Is this the preferred way of doing things? I thought that it might be better if I encrypt the password using javascript and send it to php when it is already encrypted. At least that way, the original password wouldn't be inside a POST request.

But is that really the right way? Isn't it bad if anyone can see what kind of encryption I'm using?

Comment: The correct way is to use HTTPS to secure the password in transit, and use a slow hashing algorithm server-side made for passwords (*not* SHA256, or any other SHA family member, those are fast hashes and don't have salts).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I am using HTTPS. I was just wondering where the hash should be done. Whatever hash that is.

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for your advice. I will do some research on it, starting from the link you provided!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to realize that encrypting stuff client side does not solve anything. The moment you send something encrypted and the server uses that to authenticate the user, that encrypted value becomes the de-facto password. An attacker would only need to intercept a request, read the encrypted password and send the same request again. 
Nothing is gained by encrypting client side.

The preferred solution is to store salted password hashes server side, send credentials unencrypted but using SSL/TLS, then calculate the hashes for the sent credentials server side and compare them with the stored ones.

Maybe take a look here:

Session Management Cheat Sheet - OWASP 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

> Said password is then sent to php, which in its turn, encrypts it using SHA-512 and adds it to database.

Might want to learn [how to store passwords safely](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) instead.

> I thought that it might be better if I encrypt the password using javascript and send it to php when it is already encrypted. At least that way, the original password wouldn't be inside a POST request.

See: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/). TLS is the correct solution for this problem and many others like it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links you provided me with. They were very helpful!